# How to apply conditional formatting to Word cells using RGB colours based on cell contents

Tags: vba, ms-word, rgb

I've got about 100 large Word documents with approx. 50 tables in each. I'm trying to find a way to quickly format them (using VBA) so I don't have to manually colour each cell.

I need to colour cells based on their content with specific RGB colours. For example: cells that are "Very good" or "Minor", need to be filled in RGB 112,173,71. Cells that are "Good" or "Moderate" need to be RGB 169,208,142.

[Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7nKA.jpg)

I have about 10 or so different word combinations that need to be coloured.

I've looked up a few conditional formatting questions but most seem to colour cells based on numeric/integer value rather than text.

Any help would be great.

Comment: What specifically is the problem though? What is preventing you from doing this?

Comment: I'm very new to VBA coding so was after some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should get you going. You can add extra Case statements for your different word combinations and adjust the RGB values:

```
Dim objTable As Table
Dim iRowCounter As Integer
Dim iColumnCounter As Integer

Dim lngVeryGoodColor As Long
Dim lngGoodColor As Long

' Predefine colors
lngVeryGoodColor = RGB(112, 173, 71)
lngGoodColor = RGB(169, 208, 142)

' Loop through all tables in document
For Each objTable In ThisDocument.Tables

    For iRowCounter = 1 To objTable.Rows.Count

        For iColumnCounter = 1 To objTable.Columns.Count

            ' Get Table cell
            With objTable.Cell(iRowCounter, iColumnCounter)

                If InStr(.Range.Text, "Good") > 0 Then .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = lngGoodColor
                If InStr(.Range.Text, "Moderate") > 0 Then .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = lngGoodColor
                If InStr(.Range.Text, "Very good") > 0 Then .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = lngVeryGoodColor
                If InStr(.Range.Text, "Minor") > 0 Then .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = lngGoodColor

            End With

        Next

    Next

Next
```